Como remover guias e estruturas de tópicos ao exportar para pdf o documento Google Docs pela api de exportação?
Estou usando a API do Google Docs para ter um RTE para o usuários, porém se o usuário adicionar Guias ou tópicos no documento conforme na imagem quando eu vou exportar para PDF ele aparece lá e basicamente é criado só uma pagina para ele conforme na imagem.
Esse é o meu código para exportar em PDF:
 public function getDocumentPdfByGoogle($accessToken, $document_id) {
        $newTokenForUser = $this->authGoogle('refresh_token');

        try {
            $apiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{$document_id}/export?mimeType=application/pdf";

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                "Authorization: Bearer {$newTokenForUser['access_token']}"
            ));
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            $docBlob = $response;

            return $docBlob;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Erro na solicitação: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
    } 

Sendo assim, na hora de exportar para PDF é possível solicitar para a API somente o conteúdo dentro do "documento" como o header, body e footer? Se não, é possível mandar algum parâmetro para não permitir a criação de Guias e Estruturas de Tópicos na hora que a API criar o documento?
public function createDocument($accessToken, $google_document_id) {

        $ch = curl_init();
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            "Authorization: Bearer {$accessToken}",
        ];

        if ($google_document_id) {
            // Se um ID do documento do Google for fornecido, copie pois é o ID do modelo do workspace
            $apiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{$google_document_id}/copy";
            $postData = json_encode(['name' => 'Título']);
        } else {
            // Se nenhum ID for fornecido, crie um novo documento
            $apiUrl = "https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents";
            $postData = json_encode(['title' => 'Título']);
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $err = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if ($err) {
            // Tratar erro aqui
            // echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            $data = json_decode($response, true);
            return $data;
        }
    }

Desde já, agradeço.
